# ValueError: list.remove(x): not in list, error raised when trying to remove item

Tags: python

I am making a simple 4 digit password-guesser, and in my efforts to make it more efficient by narrowing down the search scope (by removing items from the database), I have run into a ValueError. In my code, I have stored a list of all possible 4 digit combinations, and if the password guesser finds incorrect combinations, it will remove them from the database in order to avoid repeated attempts of the same combination, i.e minimising a combination like: 1234, from being used over and over again.

This is the code:

```
while guesspassword != password:
  guesspassword = random.choices(database)
  if guesspassword != password:
    database.remove(guesspassword)
  elif guesspassword == password:
    print("Your password is: ", "".join(guesspassword))
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to catch the exception. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: `random.choices` returns a list. Did you indend to use `random.choice`?

Comment: @chepner - and once random.choice is used, the value will be in the list and there should be no need for an exception handler.

Comment: Regarding tdelaney's comment, `'somepassword'` and `['somepassword']` are not the same thing.

Comment: I see where you are going. Yes, I did intend but now I realise that I don't need to use it. Do you have any suggestions to cycle through the list, and test out each combination?

Comment: Why pick one at random at all? Just iterate over the list one by one. You can shuffle the list first if you think the order in which you try passwords makes any real difference.

Comment: Your code will work once you do `choice` instead of `choices`. You could just pop from the end of list list (that's the most efficient way to remove from a list). But random is kinda nice too.

Comment: Or, since you are only verifying a known password against a database, just check if `password in database` is true. No need to reimplement it.

Comment: You don't even need to pop. `for i in range(10000): ...` will cycle through them all.

Comment: Alright I figured it out, thanks for your help.